# Error Deploying portlets

Tags: weblogic, portal

I am trying to setup some boiler plate code in my local workspace which uses weblogic10.3. I have a documentation that asks me to import Content.jar from /wlportal_10.3/content-mgmt/lib into window->preferences-->Weblogic-->Shared Library which I did. However when I try to deploy portlet this is the error am getting

> Error Deployer BEA-149107 An attempt was made to deploy library 'content' with specified specification version '10.3.2' and implementation version '10.3.2 '. However, the library manifest has specification version '10.3.2' and implementation version '10.3.2'

Comment: Can you check the `MANIFEST.MF` in the content.jar for `Specification-Version:`

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Vendor: Oracle
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.0
Implementation-Title: Oracle WebLogic Portal  
Implementation-Version: 10.3.2 
Specification-Vendor: Oracle
Specification-Title: Oracle WebLogic Portal
Created-By: R27.6.4-18_o-117227-1.6.0_14-20090623-2105-windows-ia32 (B
 EA Systems, Inc.)
Implementation-URL: http://www.oracle.com
Specification-Version: 10.3.2.....This is the content both of them are same.